# Apache VHost Redirect /dir/ to subdomain

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2, rewritecond, bitnami

I had applications running on the following variable links:

```
www.example.com/topics/vardir/show
www.example.com/education/topics/vardir/vardir/show
www.example.com/literacy/topics/vardir/show
www.example.com/literacy/topics/vardir/vardir/show
```

I have had to move these to a subdomain:

```
www.subdomain.example.com/topics/vardir/show
www.subdomain.example.com/education/topics/vardir/vardir/show
www.subdomain.example.com/literacy/topics/vardir/show
www.subdomain.example.com/literacy/topics/vardir/vardir/show
```

The [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) site is now a Wordpress site, running Lightsail Bitnami.

I would like to update [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) vhost file with a rewrite rule so people accessing the old links are redirected to the new subdomain.

I already have a rewrite rule working for a variable link with
`?elem=icon_file969` at the end
which redirects to a subdomain:

```
www.domainname.com/education/topics/vardir/vardir/show?elem=icon_file969


 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)elem=[^&]+(&|$) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainname\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/show/?$ https://subdomain.domainname.com%{REQUEST
_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've got this working for another query I needed, I'm just struggling with the question above -

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)elem=[^&]+(&|$) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainname\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/show/?$ https://subdomain.domainname.com%{REQUEST
_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]

Comment: You should update/edit your question to add additional information. Unformatted code in comments is impossible to read (characters are missing due to the formatting). However, that is a "redirect", not a "rewrite" (that you are asking for in the question)? Is that what you require? But what you are asking is then _much_ simpler than the rule you've posted... but what parts are _variable_ in the question? That just looks like 4 static redirects?

Comment: Never use a 301 until you've get everything sorted and stable with a 302

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the question. They are not simply 4 static redirects, as each one has 1 or 2 variable directories.

Comment: So, from your edit, I assume `vardir` is a "variable directory" (a single path segment) and the rest is static? And by being variable, I assume letters a-z only? Or alphanumeric? Including hyphens? Underscores?

Comment: Correct, the vardir is a variable directory, it contains alphanumeric characters and underscores. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments, `vardir` is a variable directory name that can contain alphanumeric characters and underscores. The other path segments are *static*. Since you are wanting to "redirect" (not "rewrite" as stated initially) to the same URL-path as requested then you can do this with a single rule.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/topics/\w+/show$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/education/topics/\w+/\w+/show$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/literacy/topics/\w+(/\w+)?/show$
RewriteRule ^/?((education|literacy)/)?topics/\w+(/\w+)?/show$ https://www.subdomain.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `\w` shorthand character class is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (alphanumeric mixed case and underscores).

Any query string on the initial request is passed through unchanged.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* is a more general regex and matches all URLs that need to redirect plus many more that don't. The preceding `RewriteCond` directives then narrows the selection down to just those that should redirect.

Comment: Thanks for this. The single rule makes sense. I've just tried it and it's working.